# add UIPickerView as subview, very weired

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, subview

recently I need a solution to show a present-like pickerView for choosing data for some property, like profile.
what I did is 
1, create a empty project
2, create a AViewController which will be used as subview. And I add a pickerView and a navigation bar into that view and adjust the view's height to around 260.
3, write code in that AViewController's class.

```
class APickerViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var pickerView:UIPickerView!
let dataList = [["a","b","c","d"]]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //pickerView.dataSource = self
    //pickerView.delegate = self
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return dataList.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return dataList[component].count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return dataList[component][row]
}
```

4, write code in Main ViewController to add the AViewController's View as subview.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let pickerViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(APickerViewController.self)) as! APickerViewController

    self.view.addSubview(pickerViewController.view)
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: pickerViewController.view)

    pickerViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 300, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 300)



}
```

and also one question here actually I'm not that sure the difference. 
A:

```
let pickerViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(APickerViewController.self)) as! APickerViewController
```

B:

```
let pickerViewController = APickerViewController()
```

What's the different of A and B ? If I do some @IBOutlet settings by Interface Builder will be affected or what ?

5, go and ... get weired ...

the function

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return dataList[component].count
}
```

sometime's get called many times and sometimes not get called.

and the data was not show in pickerView and sometimes only show row 1,2 and no others and if I flick up or down those 1,2 row data disappeared.

if anyone have a better solution of using pickerView as option popup window ?

Help.

Thanks

Comment: set picker inside toolbar.

Comment: hi, Patel, could you describe more detail about your idear ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class EditViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate{ 

var picker : UIPickerView = UIPickerView()
 var toolBar : UIToolbar = UIToolbar() 
 @IBOutlet var txtFieldState: UITextField!
 var stateArray = ["Andaman & Nicobar Island","Andhra Pradesh","Arunachal Pradesh","Assam","Bihar","Chandigarh","Chhattisgarh","Dadra & Nagar"]
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
txtFieldState.delegate = self
}
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
if textField == txtFieldState{ 
            txtFieldState.inputView = picker
            txtFieldState.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
            self.configurePicker()
}
    }

func configurePicker()
    {
        picker.alpha = 1.0
        picker.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:241/255.0, green:241/255.0, blue:241/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.selectedRowInComponent(0)
        let screenRect = self.view.frame
        let pickerSize = picker.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)

        let x = screenRect.origin.x + (screenRect.size.width / 2) - (pickerSize.width / 2)

        let pickerRect = CGRectMake(x,
                                    screenRect.origin.y + (screenRect.size.height) - (pickerSize.height),
                                    pickerSize.width,
                                    pickerSize.height)

        picker.frame = pickerRect

        let toolbarSize = toolBar.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
        toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(x,pickerRect.origin.y, // right under the picker
            pickerSize.width, // make them the same width
            toolbarSize.height)

    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
        dropState = row
        txtFieldState.text = "\(stateArray[row])"
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
    {
        return stateArray[row]
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {

        return stateArray.count
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Comment: hello Patel, thanks for your sharing. and I think this should be fine, if you use antoher ViewController when Edit. What  I met strange is when I try to add pickerView as a subview. e.g. profile page, a tableview, when you select one row, then the pickerView will show and the weired thing happen. Have you tried that before? (add pickerview as a subview, for reusing purpose )